# Spring REST Api respond with empty body + 403 Forbidden on runtime exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I created a Spring Boot Rest Api with custom JWT authentication.
My problem is that when I'm sending for example a request with an expired, or invalid JWT token, I'm getting an exception like this:

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA512
```

**Which is obvoiusly OK, but the response body is empty and therefore the client has no clue why is the 403 error.**

Problem is same with Spring's BadCredentials Exception etc...

**How do I convert these exceptions into custom error responses instead of "403 forbidden"?**

Spring Web Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        JWTAuthenticationFilter filter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl(AUTH_URL);

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(filter)
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

JWTAuthenticationFilter

```
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {

            String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String(req.getInputStream().readAllBytes())));

            AuthenticationDetails details = new Gson().fromJson(decoded, AuthenticationDetails.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            details.getUsername(),
                            details.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>()));
        } catch (TokenExpiredException e) {
            req.setAttribute("expired", e.getMessage());
            throw new TokenExpiredException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter

```
    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {

            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the token generated in the Authentication filter ?? Everything looks fine, but i would like to confirm that header contains the right algorithm and it was generated correctly. With the help of jwt.io you can check it.

Comment: Thank you for your time!
If I'm using the correct token, it's working, no problem with that. But when its expired or incorrect, or the login details are incorrect, I just get a "403 Forbidden" response all the time instead of eg. a json response body with "Incorrect login details"

Comment: And why not to catch the exception while validating the token and throw one of your own ???

Comment: Well I think, Spring Security does this job (validation etc) and throws exceptions. Where should I catch those? Or am I wrong?

Comment: In my case this kind of error 403 (empty body) appear when you don't have permission to do write operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are extending your `JWTAuthenticationFilter` from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, you can override `unsuccessfulAuthentication`like below:

```java
@Override
  protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);
  }
```

Now, as you can see, I've delegated the failure processing to my `failureHandler` which is of type `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

For this you need to register your custom failure handler. You can do that by implementing your handler from `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler` and override `onAuthenticationFailure`, with checking the instance of your exception thrown from `JWTAuthenticationFilter`, like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyAuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
  private final ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Autowired
  public MyAuthFailureHandler(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    if (e instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
      mapper.writeValue(
          response.getWriter(),
          ErrorResponse.of(
              "Invalid username or password", ErrorCode.AUTHENTICATION, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    } else if (e instanceof JwtExpiredTokenException) {
      mapper.writeValue(
          response.getWriter(),
          ErrorResponse.of(
              "Token has expired", ErrorCode.JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRED, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    } else if (e instanceof AuthMethodNotSupportedException) {
      mapper.writeValue(
          response.getWriter(),
          ErrorResponse.of(e.getMessage(), ErrorCode.AUTHENTICATION, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    } else if (e instanceof TokenEncryptionException) {
      mapper.writeValue(
          response.getWriter(),
          ErrorResponse.of(e.getMessage(), ErrorCode.AUTHENTICATION, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    } else if (e instanceof InvalidJwtAuthenticationTokenException) {
      mapper.writeValue(
          response.getWriter(),
          ErrorResponse.of(e.getMessage(), ErrorCode.AUTHENTICATION, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
    }

    mapper.writeValue(
        response.getWriter(),
        ErrorResponse.of(
            "Authentication failed", ErrorCode.AUTHENTICATION, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
  }
```

Comment: To add to my answer, you can also create your custom exception and throw it from `failure-handler` and then catch it your `global-exception-handler` class(extending from `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`). You can search spring boot exception handler and you can get ways to configure it. This might tackle you multiple business exceptions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My JWTAuthenticationFilter is extends from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, what should I do? Sorry, I'm not really an expert.

Comment: It's all fine, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` also extends from `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. Just override the `unsuccessfulAuthentication`